# Filter pandas dataframe using multiple conditions defined in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame that I would like to filter based on multiple conditions. The conditions are passed in as a list with variable length.

Here is basic code to filter a DataFrame:

```
>>>> conditions = ["a","b"]    
>>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(["a","a","b","b","c"])
>>>> df1
   0
0  a
1  a
2  b
3  b
4  c
>>>> df2 = df1[(df1[0] == conditions[0]) | (df1[0] == conditions[1])]
>>>> df2
   0
0  a
1  a
2  b
3  b
```

If I do not know the number of conditions passed in, is there a simple way to check for all of them?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

```
df2 = df1[df1[0].isin(conditions)]
```

Answer (score 5):

NumPy ufuncs, like [`np.logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html), have a [`reduce` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.logical_or.reduce([(df1[0] == cond) for cond in conditions])
df2 = df1[mask]
```